# How to attach a library to a specific block

Tags: 8, theming

I wonder how to attach a library to a specific block. I do this:

in mytheme.libraries.yml

```
   lib-name-script:
      js:
        header: true
        js/masonry.pkgd.min.js: {}
        js/main.js: {}
      dependencies:
        - core/jquery
```

in main.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: 220,
        horizontalOrder: true
    });
});
```

and in views-view--block-some.html.twig

```
{{ attach_library('theme_name/lib-name-script') }}

<div class="grid">
    {{ rows }}
</div>
```

But from some reason this dont works. :S

On the and of file I have:

```
<script src="/themes/theme_name/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js?oxcmsf"></script>
<script src="/themes/theme_name/js/main.js?oxcmsf"></script>
```

Was I corect load js, or mistake is on some other place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript dependencies for a specific block or page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/286430/javascript-dependencies-for-a-specific-block-or-page)

Answer (score 2):

Using the **hook_preprocess_block()** we can attach the library in the specific block.

```
function hook_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['elements']['#id'] == 'YOURBLOCKID') {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'custom/global-styling';
  }
}
```

Add it in your custom module.

YOURBLOCKID - block id. get it form var_dump($variables['elements']['#id']);

custom/global-styling - Your custom library

Comment: How's this not the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

It sure looks like you are on the right track to me. I've used the same approach myself. See: https://github.com/vegantriathlete/presentation/blob/master/templates/node--slide--full.html.twig

Have you cleared the cache? Maybe the theme registry needs to be updated to reflect the template you are using.

Have you viewed the page source of the page when that block is visible to see if the javascript is being included? Maybe the javascript is being attached and you've got a bug in your main.js. You aren't following the pattern of how to attach javascript. see: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: Ah, it seems you edited your question as I was writing this answer. If I am reading your edit correctly, it does appear that the javascript is being loaded on the page. So, I'd suspect that maybe it has to do with not following the correct pattern of how to attach javascript.

Comment: In addition to the link I've given to the Drupal 8 docs you can have a look at https://github.com/vegantriathlete/presentation/blob/master/js/slide.js to see how I've done it.

Comment: Its look like the problem is on main.js and I didnt use corect  pattern of how to attach javascript. To be honest this code make me confuse. http://prntscr.com/gtktvr

Comment: Have a look at the two links I provided on using the correct pattern to attach javascript (one of which is the page you are sharing in your screen shot).

Comment: Yes, the problem was in main.js. I solve problem. Thank you a lot for help.

Comment: Your approach is addressing the issue of passing jQuery as an argument into your function. However, you are still not following the best practice of using Drupal.behaviors. This may not bite you in your current situation, but may crop up as a problem later if you end up having AJAX behaviors on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in main.js This solve my problem. Thank you vegantriathlete for help.

```
(function ($) {

    $('.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: 220,
        horizontalOrder: true
    });

})(jQuery);
```